# Minitest is not running setup method for all files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

When I run Minitest in rails with more than one file, the `setup` method is only run for one class.

For example, if I run `rails test test/controllers`, I get the expected results.  None of the controller tests have a `setup` method.

However, if I run `rails test test/models`, then the first file executed runs correctly (it contains a `setup` method), but the second file's `setup` method doesn't ever run.  If I run each model test separately, they behave as expected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds buggy. Can you spin up new rails app and create a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: What error do you get when you run the whole directory? It might be useful to setup some `puts` statements or put `binding.pry` and check the environment inside the tests.

Have you tried to put `setup` to controllers as well and check if same would happen? Maybe it's not the `setup` fault.

Comment: The error is that the instance objects instantiated in the `setup` method are `nil` when the tests execute (for the second class that runs, regardless of which one that is).

Comment: The minimal example works as expected.  This example has no models, no db, etc.  Hmm.  I wonder what could have interfered.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I'm an idiot.  I created the test files for my model helpers by copying a template file.  When I did this, I forgot to change the class names.  Thus, I had several test `rb` files that all contained the same class.  Because ruby has open classes, this had the effect of adding the tests  from each file to a single class *but* each subsequent file replaced the previous file's `setup` method.